# How to custom display numbers in CakePHP Paginator

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I'm trying to change the display of links on a search result page.This is how the links display on my page:

**1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | Next10
1 is current page.

After clicked on **Next10** link, I want it display like this:
**11** 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 | Next10

I 've spend hours on it. But I couldn't find the way to make it work. Is there any solution?

I use

`'echo $this->Paginator->link('Next10',array('page' => $this->Paginator->params('page') + 11));'`

for the view.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what do you get instead?

Comment: I use 'echo $this->Paginator->link('Next10',array('page' => $this->Paginator->params('page') + 11));' for the view. But this is what I get:  6 7 8 9 10 **11** 12 13 14 15

Comment: Please display your code here

Comment: @RonakBhatt This is my code: 
In the controller:
    'public function index() {
  $this->Post->recursive = 0;
  $this->set('posts', $this->Paginator->paginate());
 }'
In the view:
'echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(array('separator' => '')));
  echo $this->Paginator->link('Next10',array('page' => $this->request->params['paging']['Post']['page'] + 10));'

Comment: Put your whole code.... Not just a line of code in Comment

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write your own paginator function to display the numbers.  What you're after (and what Cake doesn't support) is a different modulus for pages before and after the displayed page.  Cake only supports one modulus argument:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-page-number-links